Visio 2021 - Animating a shape, making it rotate
VBA for Visio.
Here is a subroutine that rotates an arrow Shape which is on a drawing page. The END_TIMER which is called at the end of this routine just before the End If statement is a routine that adds a 100 ms delay before the routine is exited, there is also a DoEvents statement in the timer routine.
This subroutine is inside of a timed loop which is cycled every 100 ms.
The subroutine works as expected, however if I monitor the memory that the visio application is using it slowly creeps up as long as the subroutine is enabled.  The 100 ms timer and DoEvents was introduced to try to mitigate this, which it seems to have done somewhat.  Why is this happening?  I believe I declare the object variable correctly and release it once the routine is finished.
G1_STATUS = ThisDocument.G1_STATUS
G1_FAULT = ThisDocument.G1_FAULT
G1_STOP_TIME = ThisDocument.G1_STOP_TIME
G1_START = ThisDocument.G1_START

    If G1_START = "START" And G1_FAULT = "RESET" Then        'IF GEN_1_START IS = 1 AND GEN_1_FAULT = 0 THEN CONTINUE
        Set G1_LAYER = Application.ActiveDocument.Pages("Mainsingle").Shapes.ItemFromID(260)
        G1_LAYER.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLayerMem, visLayerMember).FormulaForceU = """4"""
        Set G1_LAYER = Nothing ' Release shape reference

        Set SHP_G1 = Application.ActiveDocument.Pages("Mainsingle").Shapes.ItemFromID(293)
        SHP_G1.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLayerMem, visLayerMember).FormulaForceU = """12"""
        SHP_G1.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormAngle).FormulaU = ANGLE_G1
        ANGLE_G1 = ANGLE_G1 + 0.5235986
        G1_ENABLE_CLOSE = 1
        G1_BKR_OPEN_CLOSE = "CLOSE"
        ThisDocument.G1_BKR_OPEN_CLOSE = G1_BKR_OPEN_CLOSE
        Set SHP_G1 = Nothing ' Release shape reference
    
        END_TIMER
   

    End If

Thinking that Visio might need a finite amount of time to clear the object variables we introduced the END_TIMER routine.  We have tried running this with varying delays from 20 to 100 ms.  The 100 ms delay seems to help quite a bit, however the problem still exists, just not as dramatic.  We introduced error capture logic, (not currently in the routine) and it didn't capture anything.
I am now going to try to elimiate the         "SHP_G1.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLayerMem, visLayerMember).FormulaForceU = """12"""  " from being run each time the loop passes through the sub, this line of code changes the layer and thus the visibility of the animated shape.  It only needs to be called once not each time the shape rotates.
Thanks for your help

So there is an update, it is the assigning of the shapes to a layer that is causing the problem.  I have added conditional code that bypasses those steps once the routine has run through to loop the first time.  It is reset by another routine when it is run.  The memory now remains constant while the routine is running.
